# Worpress loose permalinks every night

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with a wordpress installation:
every day at about 5 AM (verified by a croned curl command) loose permalinks settings (different pages in 404 ....).
To resolve every day I have to go to wordpress permalinks page and confirm without change anything.
I tried to disable wp_cron in wp_config but nothing.
In the log appears this:
POST /wp-cron.php?c6383b03bee56ae9095190d5088f9dba&action=wysija_cron&process=bounce&silent=1 HTTP/1.1

How I can verify which task is calling and how I can disable this task ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install and use a cron control plugin. I usually use [WP cron control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/). It allows you to view and manage all the WP crons. It will not show crontab crons (if you're using any).